# Swift - Passing custom objects as a parameter

Tags: ios, swift

I started learning Swift today and in my first test app I am getting this error:

> `TestClass` is not convertible to `AnotherClass`

The following is the **TestClass**:

```
class TestClass : NSObject {

    var parameter1 : String = ""
    var parameter2 : String = ""

    override init() {        
        super.init()
    }

    func createJob(parameter1: String, parameter2: String) -> TestClass {
        self.parameter1 = parameter1
        self.parameter2 = parameter2
        return self;
    }  
}
```

And this is the **AnotherClass**:

```
class AnotherClass: NSObject {

    private struct internalConstants {
        static let test1 = "testData"
        static let test2 = "testData2"
    }

    var current : String

    override init() {
        self.current = internalConstants.test1
        super.init()
    }

    func executeTask(testClass : TestClass) {

        if testClass.parameter1 == "abc" {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the **ViewController** where I am getting the compiler error:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let obj = TestClass()
        AnotherClass.executeTask(obj)
    }

}
```

`AnotherClass.executeTask` line is giving the compiler error.

The `obj` variable sent as a parameter on this line is highlighted by Xcode with the error

> "`TestClass` is not convertible to `AnotherClass`".

In C# or Objective C it is allowed to pass custom objects as a parameter to another methods. How can I do it in Swift?

Comment: `executeTask` is an instance method, you need to instantiate `AnotherClass()` in order to use it: `AnotherClass().executeTask(obj)`

Comment: Thank you so much for all the answers. My mistake was I was trying to call the method as static but I didn't use the "static" keyword. AlI answers and comments were helped me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's correct first the `TestClass`. This is how you should init a class like that:

```
class TestClass : NSObject {

    ....

    init(parameter1: String, parameter2: String) {
        ....
    }
}
```

Much simpler. Now, going back to your problem,

> "TestClass is not convertible to AnotherClass".

Take a look at it again. The line you've mentioned in your question. You are trying to do this:

```
let obj = TestClass()
AnotherClass.executeTask(obj)
```

This line, `AnotherClass.executeTask(obj)`, is giving you an error because indeed `executeTask()` is an instance method. You could do three ways for that.

1. add `static` keyword to the `func executeTask...` So it becomes like this: `static func executeTask(testClass : TestClass) {`
2. Instead of `static` keyword, you could add `class`. It becomes like so: `class func executeTask(....`
3. OR, better if you just instantiate the `AnotherClass`. Make a new object of `AnotherClass`. How to instantiate? You tell me. But here:

> `let anotherClass = AnotherClass()`

Answer (score 0):

Either implement executeTask as a class function

```
class func executeTask(testClass : TestClass) {
    if testClass.parameter1 == "abc" {
        return;
    }
}
```

or instantiate `AnotherClass` in `vieweDidLoad`

```
let obj = TestClass()
let another = AnotherClass()
another.executeTask(testClass: obj)
```

Note the slightly different call to `executeTask` with the argument name.

And there is really no reason for you to subclass NSObject as I see it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to keep is simple. Create an instance of `AnotherClass` inside of `ViewController`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // Create an instance of AnotherClass which lives with ViewController.
    var anotherClass = AnotherClass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let obj = TestClass()

        // Use the instance of AnotherClass to call the method.
        anotherClass.executeTask(testClass: obj)
    }

}
```